# UIPoverController creates Live bytes on each time it is used

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, instruments

I am popping up the Popover controller on an event handler. Each time this event handler gets called, the Memory footprint of my application grows. Once I dismiss the View controller , I expect the memory footprint to be reduced, but it never happens.

I used the Allocations tool in Instruments to Profile the memory.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
-(IBAction)createNewAccount :(id) sender
{

    GSNewAccountViewController *createNewAccountVC = [[GSNewAccountViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GSNewAccountViewController" bundle:nil];        
    UIPopoverController *popover = 
    [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:createNewAccountVC]; 

    popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(kScrollViewWidth, kScrollViewHeight);

    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(770,-420,320,480) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

    popover.delegate = self;

    [createNewAccountVC release];


}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:
(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {

    [popoverController release];

}
```

**UPDATE:**

I am releasing all the Outlets of the GSNewAccountController in the ViewDidUnload method of it. But even when I dismissing the Popovercontroller the vieUnDIdload method does not get called

Comment: put a breakpoint in dealloc of your rootcontroller of UIPopViewController and see whether dealloc gets called..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I have updated the question. The dealloc and viewUndidload does not get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check to see if your GSNewAccountViewController is being released when the popoverController is released.  Rather than monitoring the amount of Live Bytes, check the # of living GSNewAccountViewController objects.  To do this in the Allocations Instrument go to the upper right corner of the Instruments window, filter the allocations by typing GSNewAccountViewController in the text field.  Then check to see what happens every time you trigger the IBAction.  The # of living should go to 1 when you trigger the IBAction and go back to zero when the popoverController is released.

If the # of living GSNewAccountViewController objects never goes to zero you should check to see if you have created some sort of retain cycle within your GSNewAccountViewController class that is preventing the dealloc and viewDidUnload methods to be called.  With the retain cycle, the GSNewAccountViewController is retaining an object, which in turn, is retaining your GSNewAccountViewController.  Since both are retaining each other, their dealloc methods are not being called and the objects are never destroyed.

To test, try creating a very simple iPad project with a button on the main view with an IBAction to present a popoverController with a viewController loaded from a NIB with a plain vanilla subclass of a UITableViewController.  Looking at the Allocations instrument, it shows that the subclass is being created when the popoverController is shown and destroyed when the popoverController is dismissed.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful tip. I think my code suffers from the retain cycle. I will check it